# The meaning of という in 言うことを聞かないというのなら

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

What's the meaning of という in 言うことを聞かないというのなら?

> 言う事を聞かないというのなら
> どうしてもというのなら
> もし、君が例外だというのなら

In these examples the words in "quotes" were never directly said. Is it correct to view these usages as "indirect quotes" which represent the view/stance/etc. of the listener as interpreted by the speaker due to the listeners actions/words? Or does it serve some other function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mostly on the right track.  Those would not, however, be called "indirect quotes" if the words were not uttered in the first place.  "Interpretation" is a good word for it as the 「～～」 part of 「～～というのなら」 is only what the speaker "assumes" to be true ; He did not "hear" it.

「というのなら」 is close to "if that is the case", "if that is what it means" in meaning (even though translating is less important than understanding and becoming able to use the phrase).

There is a reason for writing it as 「いう」 instead of 「言う」.  For a quote, whether direct or indirect, 「言う」 would naturally be used because someone has actually made a statement.

You can say 「言う事を聞かないというのなら～～～」 to your pet dog, for instance, when it is not obeying you.  The dog did not say anything.  It is just you interpreting or assuming from its actions.  This is a good example because it contains both 「言う」 and 「いう」.  You say things to your dog, so that is 「言う」.